# Why Vue has additional <Root /> right now? It breaks this.$root entirely

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

If you open any CodeSandbox default Vue template, or just vue-cli default template like this

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

It will have an additional `<Root />` element.

And it breaks everything that writes `this.$root`.

Why is this happening?

Is there any way to solve this?

[image]

Comment: `new Vue(...).$mount("#app")`  this is your `<Root>` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add some data to the root Vue instance - you will see in DevTools that it is different from the data in your App component:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  data:
  {
    someTest: 123,
  },
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

What is happening has been happening for years. You can not solve it because this is by design and can not work without it.

If you want to access App instead of the root instance - then you will have to use `this.$root.$children[0]`